# How can I repair an air conditioner drain line that is broken flush with the wall?

Tags: plumbing, hvac

As you can see below, I broke the drain line off flush with the wall.  There appears to be either a union or an elbow embedded in the wall with a broken off piece of pipe in the fitting. The joint appears to be glued because I can't remove the little fragment of pipe that is left behind. What are my options for fixing this? Right now the water is dribbling out of the broken pipe and running down the side of the house instead of being discharged from the end of the pipe two feet from the wall.

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the other side of the wall?

Comment: Not really. The house is in Florida and fairly recent construction, so the walls of the first story are made of cement filled cinder block.

Answer (score 1):

However you end up fixing this do plan to use a more repairable solution that used by the original installer. It is an insane approach to cement or stucco in a glued plastic fitting like this. As a minimum the part that gets cemented in place should be made out of metal with brass or bronze being preferred over an iron type fitting. The outside pipe should be fitted to the cemented in part via a threaded connection.

If you must repair this with minimal disturbance to the cement or stucco, (its hard to tell which from the picture) then I would see a number of possibilities...

a) Work at drilling and carving out the glued in inner pipe piece bit by bit till you get it the point where you can fit a new piece of pipe in its place. You have to use much care for this because the process could put excess torque on the remaining pipe in the wall and lead to possible further breakage.

b) Try to find a suitably sized pipe thread tap and cut threads into the inner diameter of the pipe stub. Once this is done you can fit it up with the proper type of barbed brass pipe nipple fitting. To this you can attach a flexible piece of hose to go out the 2 to 3 feet from the foundation.

If you have access to the area inside the wall you may be able to simply pull the existing fitting out of the cement and install a newer more suitable type of exterior transition that the method used.

If the wall is stucco you could take a chisel to the area around the broken off fitting and enlarge the hole enough to get access to the pipe. Then you can fit up the proper type of pipe fittings and re-patch the stucco around a metal transition fitting. Stucco patching is a fairly straight forward task and should be able to completed successfully by a diligent DIY home owner.

Comment: I like the idea of a threaded fitting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use a hacksaw blade to cut through the pipe (stoping before the socket) then put a small flat blade or chisel in the groove you have cut in the pipe, twist the tool to break the glue and the inside pipe will peel out of the socket. The other option is to put plumbers glue in the pipe and set fire to it to melt the glue around the pipe but as I cant see what is behind the wall I wouldnt do that in this case

Answer (score 0):

There are three methods for removing glued PVC pipe fittings, that I'm aware of.

## Heat

If the bit of pipe that's stuck inside the fitting is heated, the bond can be broken and the pipe removed.  They make [expensive specialized heating tools](http://www.pipedebonder.com/products.html) for this, or you can [burn it out!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfezjNDNxNo)

[image]

## Reaming

In this method, the pipe is bored out of the fitting.  [Expensive specialized reamers](http://www.wheelerrex.com/wheeler-rex-professional-tools/catalog/pages/wheeler-rex-professional-tools-catalog-page-41.html) are used.

[image]

## Cutting

With this method, there can be quite a bit of collateral damage. The idea here is to simply remove the fitting by cutting it off, which means you'll first have to have access to the pipe beyond the fitting (This is where the collateral damage comes in).

---

In your case you *may* be able to cut the pipe off on the other side of the wall, remove the old pipe from the hole, then simply slide a new bit of pipe through the existing foundation hole. This may not be an option depending on how the pipe was installed, but that would be the first avenue I'd explore.